# Apache 2.2.15 - ProxyPassReverse exception on redirect

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a multi domain / multi language construct on an Apache 2.2.15 which proxies the requests to https://www.domain.de.
It works fine, except I want to redirect to the main domain.

I want to redirect https://www.domain.cn/de/ to https://www.domain.de/de/.

The mod_rewrite rule works fine, the log tells me, mod_rewrite wants to redirect to the correct url.
Since ProxyPassReverse overwrites the location, it overwrites also the location of the redirect. So,

I need ProxyPassReverse for everything except the redirect. How can I do that?

I can add an environment variables ("E:redirected") to the mod_rewrite rule. But how can I check it when I use ProxyPassReverse?

I can't use no-proxy, because it's available in apache 2.4.26 and later

virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ServerName www.domain.cn

  # Proxy startpage to /zh/
  ProxyPassMatch "^/$" https://www.domain.de/zh disablereuse=on

  # Proxy all other URLs completely
  ProxyPass / https://www.domain.de/ disablereuse=on
  ProxyPassReverse / https://www.domain.de/
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_rewrite rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:orig-host} www\.domain\.cn$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/de/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} ^/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.de/de/ [R=301,L,NE]
```